# How to use a json API to display something?

Tags: php, json

I do not know any PHP but I'm trying to make a page to just echo a result which I can then use as a conky config.

This is what I have tried

```
<?php  
$content=file_get_contents("https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker");
$data=json_decode($content);

echo "Current Price: $";
echo $data->ticker->avg;;
?>
```

But I just get "Current Price: $" without the actual price.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try `var_dump($data);`

Comment: Thanks however I got Current Price: $NULL when adding this, I put it at the end not sure if thats where it should of been. Thanks

Comment: So it means, there is no json encoded output in this URL.

Comment: That means `$data` is NULL. You likely do not have valid JSON

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am assuming you're new to PHP. Welcome.
In the future, you should perform the following steps before you even start asking for help.

1. [Enable PHP error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/520857)
2. Look at the error messages if any
3. Dump the variable(s) that aren't behaving as expected
4. You'll probably have your answer by now
5. If not, *then* ask for help

In your case it's most likely because you have the PHP setting `allow_url_fopen` set to `Off`. Set it to `On` in your `php.ini` config file.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I was just doing it all from a text editor then ftping it to my test site, so I dont even have a php.ini maybe this is my issue.. Thanks

Comment: If you're using shared hosting, you're out of luck. You'll need to fetch the content using cURL instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642604/fetching-url-contents-using-php-and-curl